# How to trigger a function from click on document

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here's my situation: I've got a field that once the user double click, it'll edit the field. That's fine and working. I've got two functions: `ok` and `cancel`. Cancel disables the editing mode. ATM, the user has to click cancel to disable the editing mode. What I'd like to is to allow the editing mode to be disabled when the user clicks anywhere else on the page. How can I accomplish this with Angular?

EDIT: I'm adding my markup (Note: this is Jade):

```
tr(ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchText"s)

    td(ng-dblclick="editItem(user)", hm-double-tap="editItem(user)", ng-blur="cancelEditing()")

        span(ng-hide="user.editing") {{user.name}}

        form(ng-submit="doneEditing(user)", ng-show="user.editing", class="inline-editing-2", ng-blur="cancelEditing()")

            input(type="text", class="form-control", ng-model="user.name")

        button(class="btn btn-success mr-1", ng-show="user.editing", ng-click="doneEditing(user)")

            span(ng-click="doneEditing(user)").fa.fa-check-circle

        button(class="btn btn-warning mr-1", ng-show="user.editing", ng-click="cancelEditing(user)")

            span(ng-click="cancelEditing(user)").fa.fa-times-circle
```

As you can see, I've got a hg-repeat on user. When double click on the `td` element it makes `user.editing` true so the form shows up. the `cancelEditing(user)` makes the variable false and only the field is displayed.

I've added `ng-blur="cancelEditing()" on the`tr`,`td`,`span`and`form` and none of it worked.

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: I assume you want to have an "inline editor", why not use existing one, like : http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-blur` to bind your cancel event to the element. It will fire when the element loses focus.

IE: `<input ng-blur="cancel()" />`

Note: The cancel function must be within **scope**.

[Angular ngBlur Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

---

**Update from comments:**

Give the input element focus when your double tab event fires making the field editable. Your blur event is likely not firing because the input element never had focus.

You could do this from inside your editItem function or from inside the directive.

As an example:

```
yourApp.directive('hmDoubleTap', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attr){
        if(doubleTap) {
            // Fire editItem(user)
            // You could add your .focus() inside editItem().

            // Or focus the first input element at the end of the directive.
            element.find("input")[0].focus();
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I've edited my question with some code with my full code. I've tried adding `ng-blur="cancelEditing()" on several elements (td, tr, span, input and form) and none worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

b1j's answer would work only if the element gains focus. Does hm-double-tap directive focuses the element after double click? If not you will have to trigger focus in editItem function.

Comment: Currently it doesn't but that would be a nice addition actually. How could I add focus to my function?

Comment: Try something like this in the editItem function:  user.target.focus();

Answer (score -3):

Another approach would be to handle the click event on any other element like this:

```
$('#field-no-edit').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#field-edit').show().focus();
});
$('body').on('click', function(e){
    console.log($(e.target).attr('id'));
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') != 'field-no-edit') {
        console.log('not');
        $('#field-no-edit').text($('#field-edit').val());
        $('#field-edit').hide();
        $('#field-no-edit').show();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_/4y450m00/)